# Any way to advertise preferred IPv6 address with rtadvd

Tags: freebsd, ipv6, ip-address

I have both native and HE-tunnel IPv6 addresses on my router (FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p20). 
Hurricane electric prefix is static, native prefix is not guaranteed to be static, it is obtained by prefix delegation(using `dhcp6c`) from my provider.

Local network is configured by SLAAC.

HE-tunnel performs at about 50-70Mbit/s, while native network has 200Mbit/s. But native IPv6 is not guaranteed legally and it was actually out for a couple of months.

What I am trying to do is to make my router advertise the native address as a preferred, so that on clients machines default source address selection used the native address.

It's easy to add a prefix policy to make HE-address of lower priority on the client OS:

```
netsh interface ipv6 add prefixpolicy 2001:470::/32 precedence=10 label=6
```

But I also have Android clients which can't do this.

I did not find a way to make a prefix preferred or set preferred lifetime to 0 for only one prefix in `rtadvd.conf`

There's an option to add another interface/virtual host/jail solely for HE-tunnel router and advertise it with `raflags:l`, but maybe someone knows better solution?

Comment: radvd can set preference on advertised routes, but I don't know about rtadvd. Of course then the host OS has to actually pay attention, and many don't.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, it seems the option is there, but can't make the daemon work because of `can't join ipv6-allrouters on int1` for different simplest configurations I tried... I'll give it another try tomorrow.

Comment: @MichaelHampton found a way to set it in rtadvd (`:rtprefix="2001:470:xx:xx::":rtflags=l:`): `Route Info: 2001:470:xx:xx::/64 (pref: low, ltime: 30m)`
 - it really only changes metric to 4106 for the route to the subnet in client's routing table, but does not change prefix policies table...